# How to implement junit test case for Configuration class?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, spring-boot-actuator, testcase, health-check

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator","/actuator/health").permitAll();
    }
}
```

How to implement the test case for the above class??

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write an integration test using the RestAssured framework and have it hit the actuator endpoint. Would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnSuccessWhenHittingActuator(){
        given()
            .port(port)
            .when()
            .get("/actuator")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value));
    }
}
```